# How to take non-english characters from UITextField and consider them as normal characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uitextfield

i have a database that contains non-english words ( for those who wonders turkish letters). And i have an algorithm which compares the input with database.

So my problem is this; in my database all the strings are written with turkish characters. So lets say i have  thıs element to compare `heyyö`. When user enters `heyyo` it won't find it since they are considered as different words.

My first thought was put special cases and when a non-english character found consider whether english or non-english letter ( like g with ğ or i with ı) but that means a lot of brute force.

how can i do this with elegance.

Oh and user enters this inputs from a textfield if that wasn't implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removal of diacritics is called "folding." You can compare strings without regard to diacritics using the option `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.

```
[string compare:otherString options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame
```

You can similarly generate a folded string using `stringByFoldingWithOptions:locale:`.

Note that this only removes diacritics. There are many ways that characters can "seem" the same without being the same. Turkish is somewhat notorious about this because the lowercase version of "I" is "ı" (LATIN SMALL DOTLESS I), not "i". If you're particularly dealing with Turkish, you may have to account for this.

Comment: i m particularly dealing with turkish yeah. 

I store inputs to a NSMutablearray and i compare strings based comparison after a lot of middle process.Is there any other way to use this "folding concept" like i take each element from my array and make them "folded ?" and re add to array

Comment: Yes, that's what `stringByFoldingWithOptions:locale:` can do for you. It can also convert uppercase to lowercase (but again, in Turkish that's going to get you to dotless-i, not dotted-i, so just keep it in mind.) The Turkish dotted-i issue is so prevalent that it's in the `stringByFoldingWithOptions:locale:` docs.

Comment: (BTW, I'm saying all this as though you are unfamiliar with Turkish and don't mean to be rude in implying that, but I'm writing for those who may read later as well and may not understand the alphabet. I only understand it though solving the kinds of problems you're running into currently.)

Comment: hey, just ran a little test and it's pretty useful converted this "ğşıiüö" to this "gsıiuo". so when i use the same method for both input and database array i ll have what i wanted

Comment: perfect. Thnx for resolving my problem so fast.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like this:

```
NSString *input = @"heyyö";
NSData *intermediaryDataForm = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:intermediaryDataForm encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

That way, because the turkish letters are not part of ASCII, and you are allowing a lossy conversion, then it automatically changes 'ö' to 'o' when converted to the NSData form. Then converting it back to NSString solves the issue.